# Using Scala Sys Process

Tags: scala

is there a way to retrieve the actual java inputStream that correspond to the stdout of the java process being executed, when using ProcessBuilder or anything else in the package ?

Comment: I commented on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026785/how-to-issue-a-command-that-produces-infinite-output-and-return-immediately/46028869?noredirect=1#comment79160493_46028869) regarding your question

Comment: Yes so it thank you

Comment: I don't like it so much because the way to hook that to akka stream would be actually to create your stream inside ProcessIO

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just "use java":

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var br: BufferedReader = null
    try {
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
      while (true) {
        val input = br.readLine()
      }
    } finally {
      br.close()
    }
  }
}
```